# Add dynamic fields through django admin

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

I've looked around the stack but I cant find any answers.
So I have a model like this:

```
class DynamicModel(models.Model):
    config = models.JSONField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.config
```

what I want to do here now is to show the json field key-value pairs as standalone fields and also be able to edit them in the same way, like if they were each one a different field. This was the best way I could come up to create `dynamic fields`. So if I have a jsonfield like this:

```
{
    "age": 23, 
    "name": "John Doe",
    "gender": "Male"
}
```

I would have an `Age` field where I can edit the value or even remove the field alotgether. The changes would then reflect to the `JSONField`.

My approach is like this:

```
# form.py
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import DynamicModel

class DynamicModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DynamicModel
        fields = []

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields.pop('config', None)
        json_data = self.instance.config or {}
        for key, value in json_data.items():
            # Add a CharField for each key
            self.fields[key] = forms.CharField(initial=value, required=False)
            self.fields[key].label = key
            self.fields[key].widget.attrs.update({'style': 'display:block;'})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        json_data = self.instance.config or {}
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        data = self.cleaned_data
        for key, value in json_data.items():
            config[key] = cleaned_data.get(key, value)
        self.instance.config = config
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)


# admin.py

class DynamicModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = DynamicModelForm
    list_display = ['config']

admin.site.register(DynamicModel, DynamicModelAdmin)
```

But this doesnt seem to solve the problem. The result Im getting is when trying to add a new instance is :
[image]
and if I try to edit an old one its just the same but the only difference is its displaying the
`def __str__(self)`
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

An idea could be to work with an emty `ModelForm` that is then poulated dynamically:

```
class DynamicModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DynamicModel
        fields = []

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields.pop('config', None)
        json_data = self.instance.config or {}
        for key, value in json_data.items():
            # Add a CharField for each key
            self.fields[key] = forms.CharField(initial=value, required=False)
            self.fields[key].label = key
            self.fields[key].widget.attrs.update({'style': 'display:block;'})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        json_data = self.instance.config or {}
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        data = self.cleaned_data
        for key, value in json_data.items():
            config[key] = cleaned_data.get(key, value)
        self.instance.config = config
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

We thus add fields, more or less like you defined this yourself. When we want to save the item, we then regroup the fields into a dictionary, and save this to the instance.

Comment: This doesnt seem to work with my current implementation. Do I need to maybe create a custom template for this?  Or add something else Im missing?

Comment: @haduki: what is not working? The form fields don't show up, these don't get saved, you get an error?

Comment: Only the __str__ is showing and nothing else on the page. Do I have to extend the template?  Or is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot or something? I'm not really following.

Comment: hey @willeM_Van Onsem I edited the question check again please

Comment: @haduki: but here you *add* an item, so at that time the config is empty, so there are no key-value pairs. As your question says, it is only useful to *edit* an item, since then the config is filled, and therefore has key-value pairs.

Comment: but I cannot add or edit an item either its still the same. I want to be able to add/edit items as well as have be able to have multiple ones

Comment: @haduki: well creating makes no sense at all, since at the time of creation... the `.config` is *empty*, so no key-values, so if there are no key-values, then how would the modelform understand what to make of it? What happens when you *edit* a record?

Comment: I cant edit one nor can I create one from the admin dashboard the way it is set up right now, it looks like in the picture. What I want to do is instead of showing a `JSONField`, to show the json field key-value pairs as standalone fields and also be able to edit / delete them in the same way, like if they were each one a different field.

Comment: @haduki: but the object you are *trying* to edit, there the JSON blob is not empty, it has key-value pairs?

Comment: yeah is not empty and it still doesnt show. if its empty it doesnt show anything. both cases look like the picture with only difference if there is an entry it shows it in the title